# Excel - Need to get a figure from one worksheet to another (it's complicated)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have an Excel workbook with 2 worksheets.

One worksheet is for the input of stock transactions, the other has an overview of the portfolio.

So on the portfolio worksheet I would like to have a column with the total number of each stock.

Now to get this I would need a formula to check the name of the stock on the portfolio worksheet, say this is in B column, and then find the last input of this stock on the transactions worksheet (C column), and finally get the total number of stocks I have calculated on that row, say on J column.

Example:

### Portfolio Worksheet

```
  B    |      C       |         F             |
Stock  | Last Price   | Cumulative Units      |
IBM    |     ###      | (formula needed here) |
```

### Transactions Worksheet

```
  A   |   C    |         J        |
Date  | Stock  | Cumulative Units |
 ###  |  IBM   |   10000          |
 ###  |  IBM   |     20000        |
 ###  |  IBM   |       30000      |
```

I need a formula in cell F of the portfolio worksheet to check the value of B column (name of stock), and then search in the Transactions worksheet my last input of that stock and output the cumulative Unit figures on that row, e.g., 30,000.

I'm trying to make an Excel version of an online Google sheet portfolio tracker and the formula on the Google sheet is

> `=iferror(INDEX(arrayformula(filter(Transactions!J:J,Transactions!C:C<>"",row(Transactions!C:C)=max(if(Transactions!C:C=B2,row(Transactions!C:C),0)))),1),0)`

Comment: Please give an example (can use simplified data).

Comment: Not a duplicate of that question; in this one, there are multiple rows that say `IBM` and the OP needs to find the last one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Excel solution is similar to what you’re using on Google:

```
=INDEX(Transactions!J:J, MAX(IF(Transactions!C:C=B2,ROW(Transactions!C:C),0)), 1)
```

The trick that you may be missing is that this is an array formula,
so you must type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> when you enter it.

The `IF(Transactions!C:C=B2,ROW(Transactions!C:C),0)` part creates a virtual array
that looks like `{ 0, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0, … }`,
reflecting the fact that `IBM` appears on rows 2, 3, and 4 on the Transactions sheet. 
`MAX` picks the last one; i.e., the highest row number. 
And then the `INDEX` pulls the value from that for in the `Transactions!J` column.

Comment: Many thanks for taking the time to explain this, and it works great!